# Nested table loops to format data, PL/SQL

Tags: loops, plsql, scope

I am trying to format data returned from a cursor to JSON by looping through the records and columns without having to explicitly call on each column name. From what I've researched this vary well may not be a simple task or at least as simple as I'm trying to make it. I'm wondering if anyone else has tried a similar approach and if they had any luck.

```
declare
   type type_cur_tab is table of employees%rowtype
   index by PLS_integer;

   type type_col_tab is table of varchar2(1000)
   index by binary_integer;

   tbl_rec type_cur_tab;
   tbl_col type_col_tab;
begin
   select * BULK COLLECT INTO tbl_rec
      from employees;

   select column_name BULK COLLECT INTO tbl_col
       from all_tab_columns
       where UPPER(table_name) = 'EMPLOYEES';

   for i IN 1..tbl_rec.COUNT Loop
       for j IN 1..tbl_col.count Loop
           dbms_output.put_line(tbl_rec(i).tbl_col(j));
       end loop;
   end loop;
end;
```

It throws an error saying 'tbl_col' must be declared. I'm sure this is bc it's looking for 'tbl_col' listed inside 'tbl_rec'. Any help is greatly appreciated.

NOTE:  I'm aware of the built in JSON conversion but I haven't been able to get it to as fast as I'd like so I'm trying to loop through and add the appropriate formatting along the way.

Comment: You are combining metadata (ALL_TAB_COLUMNS) with application data (EMPLOYEES).  You can only do so through dynamic programming, which will be complicated with PL/SQL like this.  It is also highly unlikely that your hand-rolled code will be faster than Oracle native libraries.  So probably you should post your built-in program here and ask people whether *that* can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to specify field of tbl_rec(i) in this manner.

Try this:

```
declare 
  v_cur sys_refcursor;
  col_cnt number;
  desc_t dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  c number;
  vVarchar varchar2(32000); 
  vNumber number;       
  vDate date;       
    v_result clob:='';
    rn number:=0;
begin

    --Any sql query or pass v_cur as input parameter in function on procedure
    open v_cur for 
    select * from dual;
    --------
    c:=dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(v_cur);

    dbms_sql.describe_columns(c => c, col_cnt => col_cnt, desc_t => desc_t);
    for i in 1 .. col_cnt
        loop
            case desc_t(i).col_type
                when dbms_types.TYPECODE_DATE then 
                    dbms_sql.define_column(c, i ,vDate);
                when dbms_types.TYPECODE_NUMBER then 
                    dbms_sql.define_column(c, i ,vNumber);
                else 
                    dbms_sql.define_column(c, i ,vVarchar,32000);
            end case;
        end loop;

    v_result:='{"rows":{ "row": [';

    while (dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c)>0)
        loop
            if rn > 1 then v_result:=v_result||','; end if;
      v_result:=v_result||'{';
            for i in 1 .. col_cnt
                loop
                if (i>1) then v_result:=v_result||','; end if;
                case desc_t(i).col_type
                    --Date
                    when dbms_types.typecode_date then 
                        dbms_sql.column_value(c,i,vDate);
                        v_result:=v_result||' "'||desc_t(i).col_name||'" :"'||to_char(vDate,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')||'"';
                    --Number
                    when dbms_types.typecode_number then 
                        dbms_sql.column_value(c,i,vNumber);
                        v_result:=v_result||' "'||desc_t(i).col_name||'" :"'||to_char(vNumber)||'"';
                    --Varchar - default
                    else
                        dbms_sql.column_value(c,i,vVarchar);
                        v_result:=v_result||' "'||desc_t(i).col_name||'" :"'||vVarchar||'"';
                end case;

                end loop;
            v_result:=v_result||'}';            
        end loop;
        v_result:=v_result||']}}';
        dbms_output.put_line (v_result);
end;
```

Also you can generate XML from ref cursor with DBMS_XMLGEN package and then translate xml into json with xslt transformation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, unfortunately it is slower than the XML-JSON conversion. But being able to loop through a table with out explicitly calling the column was what I was after. I will probably post a specific question, in the future, regarding the plausibility of generating a JSON string as opposed to using the XML/xslt method in terms of performance.